# Convert listbox items of type "objects" to type "int"

Tags: c#, arrays, types, listboxitem

So I have a project to make a bank account system with a deposit function. I cannot however deposit the amount entered into the textbox because the items in the listbox are of type "object". How can I change the data type of the items in the listbox from "object" to "double". ---------FYI: THIS IS HOMEWORK----------

This is how I have declared my arrays:

```
    double[] accountbalances = {1348.36, 4456.63,2247.50,8175.86,4721.83,7815.35,3573.02,1603.53,4732.36, 2620.32};

    string[] accountnumbers = {"991364", "103655", "830087", "963216", "216329", "546188", "969200", "211794", "992629", "451876"};
```

This is how I have my arrays displayed in a listbox:

```
    foreach (double balance in accountbalances)
        {
            lstAccountBalances.Items.Add(("$") + balance);
        }
        foreach (string account in accountnumbers)
        {
            lstAccountNumbers.Items.Add(account);
        }
```

I'm trying to add(depositamount) to the selected account in the listbox but it returns an error saying the casting is wrong and that the items in the listbox are of type "object" rather than type double as i have defined for the array.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double depositamount = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);

        if (depositamount > 0 && lstAccountNumbers.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            int account = lstAccountNumbers.SelectedIndex;

            double balance = (double)lstAccountBalances.Items[account];

            lstAccountNumbers.Items[account] = depositamount + balance;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Value Geater Than 0 and Select An Account Number ", "INVALID", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is `C#` correct?  You should update the tag.

Comment: Well now more people will look since it's a popular language.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank You! (Obviously)I'm new to this site and C# so thanks for the assist :)

Comment: Here's a hint unrelated to your question, don't use double or float for currency values. It causes rounding issues. Use Decimal instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't added a double to the listbox, but a string instead, since you added the `$` character in front of it.

Set the

```
lstAccountBalances.FormatString = "c"; // c means currency
```

somewhere in the beginning (in the designer, for example), and then add the numbers without the dollar sign:

```
lstAccountBalances.Items.Add(balance);
```

after that, they will remain `double` and you can cast them back from `object`

Comment: Its always the little things -____- Thank you very much for pointing that out.